# installing conda packages in docker via dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a `Dockerfile` recipe:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 
 
RUN exec bash \
    && . /root/.bashrc \
    && conda init bash \
    && conda activate \
    && conda install -y pandas=1.3
```

When I use the command:

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

The image builds fine, however `pandas` is not installed. How can I install packages in conda using a dockerfile ??

Comment: What is you just do `RUN conda install -y pandas=1.3` instead of the chain of commands in your last RUN? Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Is this the complete`Dockerfile`?

Comment: yep, it is......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get done like that:

```
ARG UBUNTU_VER=18.04
ARG CONDA_VER=latest
ARG OS_TYPE=x86_64
ARG PY_VER=3.9
ARG PANDAS_VER=1.3

FROM ubuntu:${UBUNTU_VER}
# System packages 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq curl wget jq vim

# Use the above args 
ARG CONDA_VER
ARG OS_TYPE
# Install miniconda to /miniconda
RUN curl -LO "http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-${CONDA_VER}-Linux-${OS_TYPE}.sh"
RUN bash Miniconda3-${CONDA_VER}-Linux-${OS_TYPE}.sh -p /miniconda -b
RUN rm Miniconda3-${CONDA_VER}-Linux-${OS_TYPE}.sh
ENV PATH=/miniconda/bin:${PATH}
RUN conda update -y conda
RUN conda init

ARG PY_VER
ARG PANDAS_VER
# Install packages from conda 
RUN conda install -c anaconda -y python=${PY_VER}
RUN conda install -c anaconda -y \
    pandas=${PANDAS_VER}
```

Answer (score 7):

As most as possible, if the software is available as "static" binary, use Docker multi-stages or "COPY from":

```
# Will copy from existing Docker image
COPY --from=continuumio/miniconda3:4.12.0 /opt/conda /opt/conda

ENV PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH

# Usage examples
RUN set -ex && \
    conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no && \
    conda info -a && \
    conda config --add channels conda-forge && \
    conda install --quiet --freeze-installed -c main conda-pack
```

So you dont need to install curl / gzip / wget first in the image, code is cleaner & smaller end cached is better.

Comment: How do you know what to copy from the static binary? When you lay it out as /opt/conda, it seems obvious that that would be the case but do you have to investigate the static binary in question to know this works?

Comment: I dont have good technic for that, just searching on internet or try with read-only "docker run" and specify volumes